# how to get rid of unneccessary vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a div that holds an element of a log-window, showing user-input and system-output. That output might be wider than the div, so I added `overflow-x: auto` - but unfortunately that gives a unneccessary vertical scrollbar that I'm not able to get rid of. The element fits perfectly (in fact there's useable space below to extend)...

No fiddle, sorry - but screenshot and html [here](http://mbaas.de/v52/mylog.html).

[image]

Comment: Try adding `overflow-y: hidden`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your **CSS**:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Comment: `overflow-x: scroll ` ALWYS added a scrollbar, so I used `overflow-x: auto`. `overflow-y:hidden` did it - though it feels "unclean" - this should not create any overflow, there should not even be a need to hide anything...